# How to Use dbt union_relations Macro to Redefine Columns with Arithmetic Operations?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, union-all

I'm using the dbt macro union_relations to combine several views into one. In this process, I want to redefine an existing column while creating this new view. Specifically, I want to perform an arithmetic operation on the 'COSTS' column. More precisely, I want to add the VAT to the 'COSTS' column to obtain a new column that represents the costs including the VAT.

Here's a temporary code snippet of what I have so far:

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
    relations=[
      ref('ADS.ALL_ADVERTISEMENTS_V'),
      ref('ADS.ALL_OOH_V'),
    ],
    exclude=['_DBT_SOURCE_RELATION']
) }}
```

This code successfully performs the UNION operation on the selected relations. However, I need guidance on how to redefine the 'COSTS' column as follows within the same operation:

- Rename 'costs' to 'costs_no_vat'.
- Calculate 'costs_vat' as 'costs * 1.077'.

How can I achieve this transformation using the dbt framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dbt_utils.union_relations` macro simply returns a SQL statement. With that in mind you can place the macro into a CTE and query it like any SQL statement. Additionally, we can use the new [Snowflake `select * rename` feature](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select) to rename the column.

```sql
with unioned as (
  {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
      relations=[
        ref('ADS.ALL_ADVERTISEMENTS_V'),
        ref('ADS.ALL_OOH_V'),
      ],
      exclude=['_DBT_SOURCE_RELATION']
  ) }}
)

select * rename (costs as costs_no_vat)
  , costs * 1.077 as costs_vat
from unioned
```